# Want to play a game on my mac after losing my iPad?

Tags: mac, game-center, clash-of-clans

So recently I lost my iPad and on it was Clash of Clans. I was wondering if I could continue playing it on my Mac with the Game Center account I used on it? And if so, how? I was pretty far in the game and I really do not want to wait until I get a new apple device. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Clash of Clans is not available for OS X so you won't be able to play it on your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

you can play Clash of clans on you mac or windows , you just need to download the emulator for it.

here is the link from you can download the emulator of your choice:http://techapple.net/2014/05/3-best-android-emulators-for-mac-os-macbook-run-and-install-android-app-on-your-mac-os-x-macbook-airpro/

but i prefer: Droid4X because its free and it will give you full access like you have on android device.
Download it and run it then it will download the emulator from internet. then its start installation.
1: download the clash of clans .apk file and drag drop on the emulator. 
open he google play store and login via your google account and start the game

2: if you think resolution is not correct then you can adjust the resolution as per your need from lef side menu resolution button.
3: restart the emulator and enjoy the game :)

Answer (score -2):

Any one can play clash of clans on Mac or Pc windows , all you need is a emulator which can fill your requirement. I'm using genymotion and droidX [Android emulator for Mac ,Macbook and Windows](http://alltechmess.com/top-5-android-emulator-mac/)

Answer (score -3):

You could download Bluestacks to play Clash of Clans. I have it and it's really good.